# Debezium Server Stopping connector after an error in the application's handler method: Unexpected data type 'null'', error = '{}'

Tags: debezium, cdc

I am using Debezium Server to stream CDC data from Mysql to Kinesis. I created a systemd service that executes a sh file

```
cd /home/ubuntu/Debezium_new/target

if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
  JAVA_BINARY="java"
else
  JAVA_BINARY="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
fi

RUNNER=$(ls debezium-server-*runner.jar)

exec $JAVA_BINARY -Dlogging.level=TRACE $DEBEZIUM_OPTS $JAVA_OPTS -cp "$RUNNER:conf:lib/*" io.debezium.server.Main -e LOG_LEVE_TRACE
```

I am getting the following error logged in systemd logs but I can still see systemd service is in running state.

```
Dec 12 14:39:44 ip-172-31-71-33 bash[2929]: 2020-12-12 14:39:44,586 INFO  [io.deb.con.com.BaseSourceTask] (pool-3-thread-1) Stopping down connector
Dec 12 14:39:44 ip-172-31-71-33 bash[2929]: 2020-12-12 14:39:44,586 INFO  [io.deb.con.mys.MySqlConnectorTask] (pool-3-thread-1) Stopping MySQL connector task
Dec 12 14:39:44 ip-172-31-71-33 bash[2929]: 2020-12-12 14:39:44,586 INFO  [io.deb.con.mys.ChainedReader] (pool-3-thread-1) ChainedReader: Stopping the binlog reader
Dec 12 14:39:44 ip-172-31-71-33 bash[2929]: 2020-12-12 14:39:44,586 INFO  [io.deb.con.mys.BinlogReader] (pool-3-thread-1) Discarding 0 unsent record(s) due to the connector shutting down
Dec 12 14:39:44 ip-172-31-71-33 bash[2929]: 2020-12-12 14:39:44,590 INFO  [io.deb.con.mys.BinlogReader] (xxx-xx-xx.xxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306) Stopped reading binlog after 158 events, last recorded offset: {ts_sec=1607783984, file=mysql-bin-changelog.104110, pos=52676, row=9, server_id=1432154115, event=2}
Dec 12 14:39:44 ip-172-31-71-33 bash[2929]: 2020-12-12 14:39:44,590 INFO  [io.deb.con.mys.BinlogReader] (pool-3-thread-1) Discarding 0 unsent record(s) due to the connector shutting down
Dec 12 14:39:44 ip-172-31-71-33 bash[2929]: 2020-12-12 14:39:44,600 INFO  [io.deb.con.mys.MySqlConnectorTask] (pool-3-thread-1) Connector task finished all work and is now shutdown
Dec 12 14:39:44 ip-172-31-71-33 bash[2929]: 2020-12-12 14:39:44,603 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.con.sto.FileOffsetBackingStore] (pool-3-thread-1) Stopped FileOffsetBackingStore
Dec 12 14:39:44 ip-172-31-71-33 bash[2929]: 2020-12-12 14:39:44,604 INFO  [io.deb.ser.ConnectorLifecycle] (pool-3-thread-1) Connector completed: success = 'false', message = 'Stopping connector after error in the application's handler method: Unexpected data type 'null'', error = '{}': io.debezium.DebeziumException: Unexpected data type 'null'
Dec 12 14:39:44 ip-172-31-71-33 bash[2929]: #011at io.debezium.server.BaseChangeConsumer.getBytes(BaseChangeConsumer.java:64)
Dec 12 14:39:44 ip-172-31-71-33 bash[2929]: #011at io.debezium.server.kinesis.KinesisChangeConsumer.handleBatch(KinesisChangeConsumer.java:99)
Dec 12 14:39:44 ip-172-31-71-33 bash[2929]: #011at io.debezium.embedded.ConvertingEngineBuilder.lambda$notifying$2(ConvertingEngineBuilder.java:82)
Dec 12 14:39:44 ip-172-31-71-33 bash[2929]: #011at io.debezium.embedded.EmbeddedEngine.run(EmbeddedEngine.java:812)
Dec 12 14:39:44 ip-172-31-71-33 bash[2929]: #011at io.debezium.embedded.ConvertingEngineBuilder$2.run(ConvertingEngineBuilder.java:171)
Dec 12 14:39:44 ip-172-31-71-33 bash[2929]: #011at io.debezium.server.DebeziumServer.lambda$start$1(DebeziumServer.java:139)
Dec 12 14:39:44 ip-172-31-71-33 bash[2929]: #011at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
Dec 12 14:39:44 ip-172-31-71-33 bash[2929]: #011at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
Dec 12 14:39:44 ip-172-31-71-33 bash[2929]: #011at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This is happening frequently. I went through the Debezium source code to find out any clues and here is my observation
https://github.com/debezium/debezium/blob/5aaf4d420d983ada746d3f18c49775f318febae4/debezium-server/debezium-server-kinesis/src/main/java/io/debezium/server/kinesis/KinesisChangeConsumer.java

Also every time I run this command, I can see the different output in this line of the message. Also, some data is getting streamed and immediately throwing above error.

```
Stopped reading binlog after 69 events, last recorded offset: {ts_sec=1607785979, file=mysql-bin-changelog.104117, pos=50978, row=3, server_id=1432154115, event=2}
```

I can say that getBytes method is actually getting a null value and I am not even sure on how it is possible

```
 @Override
    public void handleBatch(List<ChangeEvent<Object, Object>> records, RecordCommitter<ChangeEvent<Object, Object>> committer)
            throws InterruptedException {
        for (ChangeEvent<Object, Object> record : records) {
            LOGGER.trace("Received event '{}'", record);
            final PutRecordRequest putRecord = PutRecordRequest.builder()
                    .partitionKey((record.key() != null) ? getString(record.key()) : nullKey)
                    .streamName(streamNameMapper.map(record.destination()))
                    .data(SdkBytes.fromByteArray(getBytes(record.value())))
                    .build();
            client.putRecord(putRecord);
            committer.markProcessed(record);
        }
        committer.markBatchFinished();
    }
```

https://github.com/debezium/debezium/blob/5aaf4d420d983ada746d3f18c49775f318febae4/debezium-server/debezium-server-core/src/main/java/io/debezium/server/BaseChangeConsumer.java

```java
protected byte[] getBytes(Object object) {
        if (object instanceof byte[]) {
            return (byte[]) object;
        }
        else if (object instanceof String) {
            return ((String) object).getBytes();
        }
        throw new DebeziumException(unsupportedTypeMessage(object));
    }
protected String unsupportedTypeMessage(Object object) {
        final String type = (object == null) ? "null" : object.getClass().getName();
        return "Unexpected data type '" + type + "'";
    }
```

So How can I restart the connector without manual intervention?
Also, whats reason behind null values?

Edit 1:
This is how the ChangeEvent<Object, Object> record looks like and these are related to delete events when I tried to read binlog data

```
[key = {
        "schema": {
            "type": "struct",
            "fields": [{
                    "type": "int64",
                    "optional": false,
                    "field": "id"
                }
            ],
            "optional": false,
            "name": "XXX.XXX_XXXX.customer.Key"
        },
        "payload": {
            "id": 34390
        }
    }, value = null, sourceRecord = SourceRecord {
        sourcePartition = {
            server = XXXX
        },
        sourceOffset = {
            ts_sec = 1607860000,
            file = mysql - bin - changelog.104365,
            pos = 10732,
            row = 1,
            server_id = 1432154115,
            event = 2
        }
    }
    ConnectRecord {
        topic = 'XXX.XXX_XXXX.customer',
        kafkaPartition = null,
        key = Struct {
            id = 34390
        },
        keySchema = Schema {
            XXX.XXX_XXXX.customer.Key: STRUCT
        },
        value = null,
        valueSchema = null,
        timestamp = null,
        headers = ConnectHeaders(headers = )
    }
]
```

Comment: Could you please try to set https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.3/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-property-tombstones-on-delete to null? I've a suspicion that the problema relates to the tombstone evenets.

Comment: @JiriPechanec I think so, I did a little bit of research and I see that this is more related to deleted records in DB. And after reading more about the property in the documentation, it looks like a related one. I'll give it a try.